# Filter through a list to display data based on the status of user task

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter through an array and display data based on the click event. There are three buttons that control different actions.

1.Button rollers display all the individuals who are rolling
2.Buttons non-rollers display lazy peeps who don't roll.
3.Buttons All display all the rollers and non-rollers.

I am trying to figure out if there is any way to display all rollers with the same filterRollers() function. I understand just resetting the state of rollingData back to the original value in a different function would do the trick but I am trying to limit to using one function. I will appreciate Any suggestion regarding the best practices . Thank you

```
var data =[
    {  name="adam", task="roll" ,isrolling=true},
    {  name="jack", task="roll" ,isrolling=false},
    {  name="r2d2", task="roll" ,isrolling=true},
    {  name="spidy", task="roll" ,isrolling=false}

]

this.state={
    rollingState=data,
    rollingData=data
}   

filterRollers(status) {
    let list = this.state.rollingState.filter(roll => {
        return roll.isrolling === status
    })

    this.setState({
        rollingData:list
    })   
}   

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.filterRollers(true)}>rollers </button>
            <button onClick={this.filterRollers(false)}>non-rollers </button>
            <button onClick={this.filterRollers(something)}> All </button>


            {this.state.rollingData.map(roll=>{
                return <Something roll={roll}/>
            }

            )}
            </div>  

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to show all the rollers, you can just call the function without any parameters. And then at the beginning of filterRollers function you can check if the parameter is undefined. If it is, just return all the data. If not, filter:

```
filterRollers(status) {
  let list;
  if(typeof status !== 'undefined'){
    list = this.state.rollingState.filter(roll => {
      return roll.isrolling === status
    })
  } else{
    list = data.slice();
  } 
  this.setState({
    rollingData:list
  })
}
```

Call the function like this, when you want to show all the rollers:

```
 <button onClick={this.filterRollers()}> All </button>
```